# Populate Next Number in Column D when Column H is entered

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to auto number column D with "WFE JC" and one more to the number of the previous row in Column D.

Example: WFE JC401 becomes WFE JC402

The trigger will be on edit of Column H

Here is my script I have now thats not working:

`````
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedRange = e.range;

  // Check if the edited range is in column H (Client) and not in the header row
  if (
    sheet.getName() === "Job Card SumSheet" &&
    editedRange.getColumn() === 8 /* Column H */ &&
    editedRange.getRow() > 1 // Skip header row
  ) {
    var editedRow = editedRange.getRow();

    // Get the current "Doc No" in column D
    var currentDocNo = sheet.getRange(editedRow, 4).getValue();

    // Increment the numeric part of the "Doc No" in column D
    var nextDocNo = incrementDocNo(currentDocNo);
    sheet.getRange(editedRow, 4).setValue(nextDocNo);
  }
}

function incrementDocNo(docNo) {
  var numericPart = parseInt(docNo.match(/\d+/)[0]); // Extract numeric part
  var nextNumericPart = numericPart + 1;
  return docNo.replace(/\d+/, nextNumericPart); // Replace numeric part with incremented value
}````

This does not work at all
`````

Comment: it seems like you want to fill column D when the corresponding row in column H is _not empty_ rather than when it's edited. If that's the case you don't need a script, you can use a simple formula.

Comment: Could you please explain?

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & work out a solution. You may also use the [anonymous blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by docs community forum for ease of sharing.

Answer (score 0):

As a formula option (since you expressed interest), this may satisfy your needs.  H1:H7 has random entries that I manually entered.  Cell D1 has the formula:

> =ARRAYFORMULA("WFE JC" & (SEQUENCE(COUNTA(H1:H),1,401)))

This will populate D column as shown in the spreadsheet sample screenshot below:

[image: Sample Screenshot]

Note that with the SEQUENCE function, the third parameter is the starting number.  This can be changed to whatever number you would like to start at.

Hope this helps!